# How to display items in a widget with a next button

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a a list of items i want to display inside of a widget.

I was told that i should have a next button on the widget to show each item.

The question is i need to know how this works..Will each item be loaded as the user hits next?

I want the items to all load at once, and then the user be able to click through them with the next button..

Could some one give me greater detials on this? or an example or tutorial would be great.

Thanks

EDIT:

SO i have a list of Item Titles, and Some info about them loaded from html into an ArrayList.

What i want to do is display the items in a wigdet.
ListView is not allowed in any os older then 3.0.

What is or how is the best way to get around this to display the items?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom UI component with everything you want the list item to contain.

Then inflate this item in a MyUIComponent.java class constructor, along with any listeners you need to register.

Use a ListAdapter to point all of these UI components stored in an array/List to to ListView.

This is how I did it in 2.2.  Worked great!

Let me know if you need code.

EDIT:

Custom List adapter:

```
public class CatalogItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> //
{
private ArrayList<Product> products;
private Activity activity;

public CatalogItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Product> items, Activity activity) //
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.products = items;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) //
{
    Product product = products.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) //
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.catalog_item_stub, null, false);
            //this is the layout resource for each item
    }

    TextView priceView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.ProductPrice);
    TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.ProductTitle);

    priceView.setText(price);
    titleView.setText(product.DisplayName);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

In your activity:

Call this to setup your List:

```
protected void setupUIElements(Activity activity) //
{

    listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.CatalogProducts);

    m_adapter = new CatalogItemAdapter(activity,
            R.layout.catalog_item_stub, products, activity);

    listView.setAdapter(m_adapter);
}
```

Call this to fill the ListView with items:

```
void fillListView(final ProductResponse response) //
{
    for (Product p : response.Products) //
    {
        products.add(p);
    }
    progDialog.dismiss();
    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Wow I love it! Very Very great idea! And yeah some code would be great for example, and reference.

Comment: So how did you create the next button to allow the user to navigate though the items?

Comment: You create a click listener for the ListView, check the Android docs :)  I wouldn't recommend a "next" button for every item, though.  Try to limit the number of listeners you use.

Comment: SO for yours when the user clicks on a item in the list..the next item is displayed?

Comment: Just marked the answer correct..I forgot..But so could you give more detail about how you allow the user to see the next item in the list?

Comment: Okay so ive created a Adapter and created the view i want for the widget with the correct layout. Now how do i reference or show this inside of the widget??

Comment: You can create a property within the widget to hold anything you want - just reference the property that contains the data you want with the index returned by the selector.

Comment: Could you give me an example in the code qbove. Im sorry im a visual learner. All your help is definitely appreciated. Wish i could give extra points for your answer

Comment: You should definitely write a tutorial on this..What is your response class consisted of?